# Retrieving published (non draft) blog posts from Blogger API

Tags: api, rest, gdata-api, blogger, blogspot

I'm building a website that uses the Blogger API to display blog posts inside the site instead of linking to the xyz.blogspot.com url.  I can successfully grab posts via jQuery but am having trouble filtering the results based on whether or not the post is actually published (viewable on xyz.blogspot.com).

I've tried the "published-min" and "published-max" query parameters but they still return posts that are categorized as "drafts" in the blogger admin interface.

The goal is to build a paging system that shows one post at a time and doesn't have to retrieve every post on every page load in order to know if the post that comes after the current one is published or is still a draft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the Blogger api via jQuery only returns published blog posts as long as you are **not** logged into the Blogger admin panel in the same browser on a different tab.

Logging into the Blogger admin panel on another tab will return both draft and published posts from the same jQuery ajax request:

```
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/{blogger blog id}/posts/summary?alt=json",
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function(blogData) {

        var totalPosts = 0;

        if(blogData.feed.openSearch$totalResults)
            totalPosts = parseInt(blogData.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t);

        alert(totalPosts);

    }
     });
```